# Upload a file and Save to data extension programmatically using ampscript

Tags: exacttarget, ampscript

I am a newbee in marketing cloud and want to upload a .xls file and save its content to data extension using ampscript.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, using the Automation Studio, to set a trigger (to watch for a file with a specific name or partial name in a particular directory) and then have the automation automatically import.

That method doesn't necessarily require any AmpScript. For all the stuff I've done from Excel, I usually convert first to TXT or CSV.

Do you specifically need/want to use AmpScript?

Comment: Yes I need to specifically use Ampscript. Is there any way out?